# Error trying to GET all orders

Tags: orders, rest-api

I am getting the error below trying to get all orders using get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria');

I am using Access Token and my integration has access to ALL API.

```
{
    "messages": {
        "error": [
            {
                "code": 500,
                "message": "Server internal error. See details in report api/279047400427"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add error log. You can find
var/report/api/{your_error_report_number} this number mentioned in your given response.

Comment: Kindly check the error into magento log file and try to resolve that one.

Comment: Hello... what is the end point? I have tried /var/report/api/279047400427, but it is returning:  The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.
The product is no-longer available and has been discountinued.

Comment: check error logs and apache error logs, this error is also possible due to low memory_limit size if you have more orders than normal limit

Comment: how can I adjust the memory_limit size?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried:

```
https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[pageSize]=2
```

and I was able to retrieve 2 orders, however, orders from 2014...how can I get the most recent ones?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this endpoints which will fetch most recent orders placed

> [https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[pageSize]=1&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC](https://www.justjeeps.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5BpageSize%5D=1&searchCriteria%5BcurrentPage%5D=1&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=created_at&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdirection%5D=DESC)

you can set pagesize accordingly !!!